# Which socket type for transmission

Tags: networking, tcp, websocket, udp

I plan to use TCP, UDP and web socket instead of HTTP for client-server communication.But I have an issue, what socket type should I use for large data transmitted from CLIENT to SERVER. For example :

```
{
"name": "Product",
"properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "Product identifier",
        "required": true
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Name of the product",
        "required": true
    },
    "price": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 0,
        "required": true
    },
    "tags": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "stock": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "warehouse": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "retail": {
                "type": "number"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

For synchronous transmitting of data like this one, on which circumstances should I use the following options? Or when exactly synchronous and asynchronous transmitting options are used?

```
1- TCP
2- UDP
3- WEB SOCKET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Web Socket is just a layer over TCP.

UDP is not appropriate for large transmissions as you have to implement most of TCP yourself to get it to work right.

That leaves one choice.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers(I guess all your answers were true but i could just point one because of the system), i wonder one more thing : Can i transmit the data ,which was sent to a udp channel, to other users.For example in a fighting game?

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a bad idea for most data transmission systems.  TCP is a great choice, but you'll find that the client language support for HTTP is usually simpler to work with.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers(I guess all your answers were true but i could just point one because of the system), i wonder one more thing : Can i transmit the data ,which was sent to a udp channel, to other users.For example in a fighting game?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent large amount of data,  want acknowledgement(if data is important) then use TCP.

If you want to sent small amount of data,  don't want acknowledgement(if data is not much important) then use UDP.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers(I guess all your answers were true but i could just point one because of the system), i wonder one more thing : Can i transmit the data ,which was sent to a udp channel, to other users.For example in a fighting game?